# Use the object returned by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to find an object from an XML file. After I find the object, I want to print its details, but I'm not really sure how I can use the object I found.

This is my code:

```
var apartmentExist =
    from apartment1 in apartmentXml.Descendants("Apartment")
    where (apartment1.Attribute("street_name").Value == newApartment.StreetName) &&
          (apartment1.Element("Huose_Num").Value == newApartment.HouseNum.ToString())
    select apartment1.Value;
if (apartmentExist.Any() == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Apartment at {0} or at num {1}", newApartment.StreetName,
        newApartment.HouseNum);

}
else
{

    //print the details of apartment1
}
```

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Apartments>
  <Apartment street_name="sumsum">
    <Huose_Num>13</Huose_Num>
    <Num_Of_Rooms>4</Num_Of_Rooms>
    <Price>10000</Price>
    <Flags>
      <Elevator>true</Elevator>
      <Floor>1</Floor>
      <parking_spot>true</parking_spot>
      <balcony>true</balcony>
      <penthouse>true</penthouse>
      <status_sale>true</status_sale>
    </Flags>
  </Apartment>
</Apartments>
```

Comment: Could you provide your XML file Format?

Comment: `apartmentExist.First()`  if there is one element, `foreach(var apartment in apartmentExist)` if there are multiple. Also, you might want to rename apartmentExist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You LINQ query returns `IEnumerable<XElement>` If you expect it to return more then one element you can use `foreach` loop to print the elementss, if there is only one result you can call `.Single()` extension method to get the `XElement`, not collection:
2. Casting `XElement` to `string` is safer then using `XElement.Value` property, because it will not throw `NullReferenceException` when element does not exist. You should also use `(int)XElement` cast and compare numbers instead of `XElement.Value` and comparing it to string representation of a number.
3. You should not use `Descendants` method, Use `Elements` instead. It will make your query faster because only elements that need to be searched will be processed.
4. You should call `FirstOrDefault` and check if result is `null` instead of using `Any` and then another `First` call. It will prevent your query from execution twice.
5. Instead of returning `apartment1.Value`, which is a `string`, return `apartment1` itself. It will be `XElement` and you'll be able to get into it's content later when it's necessary.

   ```
   var apartmentExist =
       from apartment1 in apartmentXml.Root.Elements("Apartment")
       where ((string)apartment1.Attribute("street_name") == newApartment.StreetName) &&
         ((int)apartment1.Element("Huose_Num") == newApartment.HouseNum)
       select apartment1;

   var apartment = apartmentExist.FirstOrDefault();

   if (apartment == null)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Apartment at {0} or at num {1}", newApartment.StreetName, newApartment.HouseNum);
   }
   else
   {
       // you can use apartment variable here. It's an XElement
       var huoseNum = (string)apartment.Element("Huose_Num");

       // flags
       foreach(var flag in apartment.Elements("Flags"))
       {
           var name = flag.Name;
           var value = (string)flag;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: im trying to use

 Console.WriteLine(apartment.Value);

but i can see its not exactly what i need
can you show me the way you print each value separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one linq query like this:

```
var apartment =
(from a in apartmentXml.Descendants("Apartment")
where (a.Attribute("street_name").Value == newApartment.StreetName) &&
      (a.Element("Huose_Num").Value == newApartment.HouseNum.ToString())
select new { 
      street_name = a.Attribute("street_name").Value,
      Huose_Num = a.Element("Huose_Num").Value,
      Num_Of_Rooms = a.Element("Num_Of_Rooms").Value,
      Price = a.Element("Price").Value,
      Flags = (from f in a.Element("Flags")
                  select new { 
                    Elevator = f.Element("Elevator").Value,
                    Floor =  f.Element("Floor").Value,
                    parking_spot = f.Element("Floor").Value,
                    balcony = f.Element("balcony").Value,
                    penthouse = f.Element("penthouse").Value,
                    status_sale = f.Element("status_sale").Value
                    })
                 }).FirstOrDefault();

if(aparment == null) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Apartment at {0} or at num {1}", newApartment.StreetName,
    newApartment.HouseNum);
} 
else 
{
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.street_name);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Huose_Num);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Num_Of_Rooms);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Price);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.street_name);

   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Flags.Elevator);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Flags.Floor);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Flags.parking_spot);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Flags.balcony);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Flags.penthouse);
   Console.WriteLine(apartment.Flags.status_sale);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Apartments>
  <Apartment street_name=""sumsum"">
    <Huose_Num>13</Huose_Num>
    <Num_Of_Rooms>4</Num_Of_Rooms>
    <Price>10000</Price>
    <Flags>
      <Elevator>true</Elevator>
      <Floor>1</Floor>
      <parking_spot>true</parking_spot>
      <balcony>true</balcony>
      <penthouse>true</penthouse>
      <status_sale>true</status_sale>
    </Flags>
  </Apartment>
</Apartments>
";

var apartmentXml = XElement.Parse( xml );
//apartmentXml.Dump(); // This is a linqpad feature

var new_street = "sumsum";
var new_house_num = "13";


var match_apartment = apartmentXml.Elements().Where (x => x.Attribute("street_name").Value ==  new_street && x.Element("Huose_Num").Value == new_house_num );
//match_apartment.Dump();

if (match_apartment.Count() < 1 )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Apartment at {0} or at num {1}", new_street,
        new_house_num);

}
else
{
    foreach( var x in match_apartment.Elements() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", x.Name, x.Value );
    }
}
```

Comment: works great!
can i also use the flags name and print them?
i see only
Huose_Num , Num_Of_Rooms and Price before the value.

Answer (score -2):

appatmentExist is an IEnumerable so to access the individual items within it use List indexing to access an individual element

```
Comsole.Writeline(appartmentExist.toList()[0].StreetName);
```

will print the streetname for the first element found in the query above

Comment: If `aparmentExist` is an `IEnumerable` you can't use list indexing.